# React update state hook on functional component does not allow dot notation

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm getting the following error:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
```

In my functional component (not class) I have:

```
  const [ ministries, setMinistries ] = useState({
    options: '',
    selected: ''
  });
```

later in another method I try to update `ministries` by doing the following:

```
let opts = [1, 2, 3, 4];

setMinistries({
  ministries.selected: opts
})
```

Assuming ministries is the object and selected is in ministries I would expect dot notation.
ministries.selected: opts to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you can just do `selected: opts` instead of `ministries.selected: opts` to modify the `selected` state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, be aware that the `useState` updater overwrite a previous state with a new one and it does not perform any merging.
Instead, it requires you to pass the complete state each time.

However, that's not the case with `this.setState` in a `class component`.

That's something that, to my advice, is important to remember to avoid subtle undesired behavior.

So, the correct way to update your state would be:

```
setMinistries(prevMinistries => ({
   ...prevMinistries,
   selected: opts
}));
```

Comment: @FabricioG Maybe you want to merge previous `selected` with new `opts` as well?

Comment: I meant at the end of the code block.  You open it with (prevMinistries but it doesn't close.  @Claudio Cortese

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks for finding it out. I've corrected the typo

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `ministries.selected` as an object key.

You can just do:

```
setMinistries({
  selected: opts,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
setMinistries({
  ministries.selected: opts
})
```

This is bad syntax. You call the property of the object within an object.

Try

```js
setMinistries({
  ministries: {
    selected: opts
  }
})
```

or

```js
setMinistries({
  selected: opts
})
```

Comment: Your fiddle is completely wrong... You are trying to use a `hook` inside a `class component`